# Perl: index() won't work with variable like $array[$i]

Tags: arrays, perl, string-matching

I have two arrays, one containing long strings from error-logs, a second containing a list of words. I need to lookup, wether one of the words matches with any of the error-strings. I want to use index().

What I have is:
@park is a whole pages, line by line. I cut out line 1 and put it into $err1
@omit is a list of words read from a file. Contains "Kein Zugriffsrecht", "constraint violation" and the like. I Get line by line from an array (treated with `chomp()`)and put it into $fehler.

```
while (@park){
    my $i = $#park;
    $zeile1 = splice (@park,$i,1);
    @foo1 = split(";", $zeile1);
    $err1 = $foo1[1];
    
    for my $b (0..$#omit){
    $prob1 = 0;
    $fehler = $omit[$b];
#   $fehler="constraint violation";

    $prob1 = index ($err1, $fehler);
...
}
```

The point is, that `$prob1 = index ($err1, $fehler);` *always* gives -1 (not found). If I set `$fehler` to something like "constraint violation", like in the commented line above, index() will give the correct number.
What could cause this behaviour?
Regards

Comment: I would go crazy with half my code in German and half in English. How do you manage to not mix stuff up?  Especially `$err1` and `$fehler`. If you gave this to me at $work to review we might be in for an unpleasant Friday afternoon chat. - In all seriousness though, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Essentially, please [edit] your question and provide some example data for both `@park` and `@omit`. Thanks! :)

Comment: Do the elements of `@omit` have trailing newlines? (i.e., have you been calling `index($err1,"constraint violation\n")`?)

Comment: You are way ahead of where you should be. "I want to use index()" is clear signal you are doing something wrong. (Because no one really ever wants to use index) Back up 10 steps and then ask for help.

Comment: @TLP Can absolutely relate to that sentiment, but if they really want _just the index_ of the substring then `index` _is_ the tool (and much much faster than starting the regex engine)

Comment: If you can provide some sample data -- very little will do -- then we can figure out why that `index` fails

Comment: agri --- I am not sure why the question got _closed_, in particular given that you may have not even been back here yet after posting it, but once you do see this: you can still edit the question and add sample data, and then we can answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the approach in the question is fine, with details addressed below. I don't know why you specifically "*want to use index()*" here, but that's fine if you indeed *only* want to find the index of the substring. I offer a far more flexible alternative (regex).

```
while (@park) {
    my $zeile1 = pop @park;
    my @foo1 = split(";", $zeile1);
    my $err1 = $foo1[0];
    
    for my $b (0..$#omit) {
        my $prob1 = 0;
        my $fehler = $omit[$b];

        if ($err1 =~ /$fehler/) { 
            $prob1 = $-[0];     # position of last match's start
            ...
        }
        ...
     }
}
```

This tries to keep details from your code.  See below for further simplifications.  Some notes on the code posted in the question:

- `splice` is used to remove and return the last character; use `pop` for that
- `$foo1[1]` is the *second* item, not the first as stated; fixed
- I can't tell why your `index` doesn't work; perhaps `@omit` doesn't contain what you think it does? I use an alternative (regex), with which you can do a lot more.  But if you literally only need the position of the match then do fix `index`
- The loop over `@omit` is over its index. If you don't use that index further down then there is no reason to involve it; loop over elements

  ```
  foreach my $error (@omit) {
      my $prob1 = 0;

      if ($err1 =~ /$error/) { 
          $prob1 = $-[0];    # position of last match's start
          ...
      }
      ...
  }
  ```

  (I changed *fehler* to English, for language consistency)
- Top of the loop can be simplified as well

  ```
  while (my $row1 = pop @park) { 
      my @foo1 = split /;/, $row1;
      ...
  }
  ```

  I changed delimiters on `split`'s argument, to remind that it is a regex. I changed *zeile* to English ("row") for consistency
- Rarely anything is declared in the code; perhaps you declare at a higher scope?  It is beneficial to declare variables in as tight a scope as possible. Variables that aren't used outside of their loops should be declared right as they're assigned
- Mixing languages for variable names can get you crazy and can make the reader miserable (specially if they don't speak both well enough).  Either can directly lead to errors.  Why not pick one language to use consistently?

Further simplifications and cleanup may well be possible but we don't know what goes on further down in the code

- Is `@foo1` used more? If it is, do you perhaps want to *remove* the front element from it (`shift`) each time round?
- How is `@omit` processed, and what is the use of `$prob1`?  It may be possible to do all that in one statement (likely involving `map`), and brevity may be helpful for readability
- What does some typical data look like?  That may well explain why that `index` doesn't find substrings

Comment: First of all many thanks for all your comments!

Comment: The reason, why "I want to use index()" is, that I simply need to know, wether or not $err1 contains my string $fehler. If not, do something, if so, go to the next $err1 entry. 
Eventually, I found why index() did not work: the textfile containing the search phrases had windows line endings! So chomp did remove \n, but of cause did not remove \r, which caused the error.
I'd like to apologize, if my question was inappropriate - I like perl, but I'm by no means a perl evangelist. I will be more precise next time, I promise!

Comment: @agri Ah, windows line endings -- a common culprit! Good find. If you just want to know whether something's in a string then regex best reflects that intent; with `index` I thought that you needed the actual position.  (But of course you _can_ use `index`, it's just that it can  be misleading for the reader -- including yourself some months down the line when you forgot that _you_ wrote that piece of code, let alone what the code does. :)  Unless that "do something" involves the index, in which case `index` is the best tool to use in my opinion.

Comment: @agri I find your question reasonable, if perhaps a little clumsy; but that's OK, writing a good question isn't easy and this was your _first_ one.  I don't really see why it got a -1 twice and was closed. So don't feel bad about it, just write the next one better :).  The one thing that clearly was missing is some sample data; _always show some data_ :)  (Well, when possible.)